# Counting number of divs within a div, with multiple parent divs on one page of wordpress posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Sorry for the complicated title, let me try to explain.

I have Wordpress posts displaying on a category page. Each post is represented by a 300px wide div which contains the featured image.

At the top of this div I have one or more coloured bars. The coloured bar is created as a div. The posts will have different amounts of these bars...

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="colourbox">
        <div class="red" ></div>
        <div class="blue" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="colourbox">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <div class="colourbox">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a cool jQuery function which allowed me to adjust the width of these divs according to the amount of divs visible  within the parent div (colourbox)

```
// select visible children
var visibleDivs = $('.colourbox div:visible');

// use whatever width calculation you'd like...
var targetWidth = 300 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

// apply the width to the divs
visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
```

HOWEVER, this is counting EVERY visible div on the page, so with this example the width of all these bars would be a 6th of the post div, as there are 6 divs in total

Does anyone know how I would make the styling apply for each post div seperately. I think this might not be possible as there is nothing distinguishing the posts for jQuery to pick up.

Would I need to put a count in the Wordpress loop which would give each post a unique number, which I could combine with a class.

I think this fiddle is pointing me in the right direction --- http://jsfiddle.net/geko/vXcgZ/

my brain has just come grinding to a halt. Any more suggestions would be great. Maybe there is a simpler way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.each()` function which will then select each parent element and do the maths on just the children of that single element.

Try this

```
$('.colourbox').each(function(i) {
    // select visible children
    var visibleDivs = $(this).find('div').length;

    // use whatever width calculation you'd like...
    var targetWidth = 300 / visibleDivs.length - 1;

    // apply the width to the divs
    visibleDivs.width(targetWidth);
});
```

Read more about the `.each()` function here: [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom.js:15
(anonymous function) custom.js:15
m.extend.each jquery-latest.min.js?ver=3.5.2:2
m.fn.m.each jquery-latest.min.js?ver=3.5.2:2
(anonymous function)

Comment: Try using the amended answer above.

Comment: I get the same error with that too, you mean the guy who's copied you? :)

Comment: Which line is exactly erroring? It says line 15 but ofcourse the code above is only 10 lines.

Comment: sorry I got the answer now.... var visibleDivs = $(this).children('div'); works. I was calling length twice which I didnt need to. I'll mark your question as right as it was what I needed

Comment: Ahh awesome, was just testing it out on codepen and got to the same conclusion but saw you left the comment. Cheers :)

Comment: @bboybeatle just for the record, if you test this solution against an empty div such as `<div class="colourbox"></div>`, it will stop adjusting the widths on anything else on the page beyond that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function which will look at each parent element and do the calculations on the children of that element exclusively.

Try this:

```
$('.colourbox').each(function(){

    var colourbox = $(this);
    var visibleDivs = colourbox.find('> div[class]:visible').length;

    // division by zero 
    if(!visibleDivs) 
        return;

    visibleDivs.width(300 / visibleDivs - 1);
});
```